# Prevent dart generic from accepting List of itself

Tags: list, dart, generics, types

I have this constructor:

```
PuzMat.fromMatrix(List<List<T>> data) {
  _layers.add(data);
}
```

By mistake I passed it a `List<List<List<T>>>` and it just swallowed it. I want to prevent that from happening, but if I check the type, my editor say it will always be false. I'm thinking generics work weirdly in dart and will accept `T` being `List<T>`. But that would be a recursive type, so I don't get why its allowed. Is there any way I can prevent the user from giving the wrong type?

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's recursive.  It's just the three levels deep.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed?  A `List<T>` is a type.  If it weren't allowed, you wouldn't be able to have a `List` of `List`s at all.

Comment: You should instead take in the value you desire

Answer (score 1):

The Dart generic system has no way to express "is not" or "does not extend" at compile-time. `List` is a completely reasonable type to pass here, and there is no fundamental reason it should be forbidden (it is not recursive). Do you even really mean List here? Is it ok to pass `Set<T>`? Why do you consider `List<List<List<T>>>` to be a particular problem type?

But if you do want to forbid it, it can only be done at runtime. For example, in your function you can add an assertion:

```
assert(data is! List);
```

This would help developers avoid this mistake (if it is a mistake).

The other (and possibly better) approach would be to declare some base type that `T` must extend, and don't extend List. This would limit what can be passed to things you actually want. But there's no way in Dart to express, at compile-time, "every type except List."

Comment: `assert(T is! List);` won't work. Or rather, it'll never fail since `T` as an expression is a value that has type `Type`, which is not a `List`. It's generally hard to compare type variables in Dart, because `is` only works with one value and one type. What you can do is, ironically, `assert(<T>[] is! List<List>);`, which creates a value of a generic class and checks it against the generic type using `is`. That will fail if `T` is a subtype of `List`.

Comment: @Irn, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you check my example? (Adding `assert` seems to work fine here as well, rather than `print`). `is!` is evaluated at runtime, not compile time if I understand correctly. Maybe I'm missing something deeper? https://dartpad.dev/?id=2496ce8a8204804d984d6024ec9851a1

Comment: (Just realized my typo in the answer. Yes, you're completely correct. I had meant to write `data`, not `T`. Fixed. Thank you.)

Comment: The expression `T is! List` is evaluated by first evaluating `T` to a value, which is an instance of the class `Type`, a `Type` object representing the type that `T` is bound to. Then it checks whether that object implements `List`, which it never does. The `assert(T is! List);` will never fail, not even if `T` is bound to `List<Object?>`. So it checks nothing.
The example you link to works because it says `x is! List`, not `T is! List`.